# Proposal for a Topic of the Week Contest - Tai Chi

Tags: discussion, status-completed, asking-questions

**Update (May 14, 2012):** We have the go-ahead from Stack Exchange to proceed with this contest (they will be sponsoring the prize). Check out the latest meta post regarding the rules and format of the contest.

- [Tai Chi Week - A Martial Arts.SE Contest](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/tai-chi-week-a-martial-arts-se-contest)

---

[World Tai Chi Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Tai_Chi_and_Qigong_Day) is coming up on April 28, and I thought this would be the perfect opportunity to generate some excellent content regarding [tai-chi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tai-chi). I know other Stack Exchange sites like Cooking and [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-plato-week) have done similar things.

Here is the basic rundown of the contest idea (gleaned from other SE sites):

- Each person who asks a question related to tai chi (and tagged appropriately) will be eligible to win a prize.
- Each question you ask will earn you one entry into a random drawing to win *Prize X* (TBD).
- There must be a minimum of X users asking questions for this contest to work.
- Questions must remain open and not have a negative score.

***Addendum:***

- Moderators are not eligible for the contest. We will be the ones picking the winner.
- A post must have at least a score of +3 to be qualify. *Get out there and participate!*

The contest could run:

- <s>During the week of April 22 until the end of World Tai Chi Day (the 29th) (too soon?)</s>
- <s>Starting on World Tai Chi Day (the 28th) throughout the week after</s>
- Whenever

The actual prize could be... something martial arts related. Both Cooking.SE and Philosophy.SE have [offered books as prizes](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/its-gluten-free-time-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize) (up to a $50 value) of the user's choice. It's a reasonable prize, but please feel free to suggest something else.

Since World Tai Chi Day crept up so quickly (sorry, I lost track of the month otherwise I would've proposed this earlier) a big help from the community here would be to spread the word along to your friends or colleagues via whatever communication channels you like — word of mouth, e-mail, Twitter, Facebook, Google+, etc.

I will get in touch with the Stack Exchange staff to see if they can sponsor a prize for this. There is a possibility an in-house network ad might be an option. Given that this is on such short notice (partially my fault for not bringing it up earlier), there isn't a guarantee of anything. The idea of was to have it to coincide with World Tai Chi Day. It's not a necessity, but a good tie-in for it. A contest like this can always happen in the future.

Nonetheless, please leave your thoughts on what you think of this. The more community support it gets, the better. Even if the contest doesn't happen, don't let that discourage you from asking more questions and contributing to the site.

Comment: I like the idea of having a contest.

Comment: Moderators are of course excluded from the drawing (but not asking questions). All questions must be in accordance with the [FAQ](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq) and the guidelines here on meta (if a question is close-worthy, it will not be included just because it's tagged [tag:tai-chi]).

Answer (score 1):

Me gusta. Let's do it. Would it make sense to have answers compete for a prize, too?

Heh. We could also have an "MMA week", say, if the NY state Senate legalizes MMA competition. However I doubt we have a sufficient combat-sport user base.

Comment: Other SE sites have a done a weekly topic contest. Suggestions come from the users so if we get enough people to buy into it and support from Stack Exchange, it is certainly something we could do. I've already sent an e-mail to Stack Exchange to see whether they will support this kind of thing. Maybe we could crowdfund or do something on our own. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: The idea for MMA week is excellent. Answers probably shouldn't have a drawing – the idea is to motivate people to ask quality questions, which in turn will draw quality answers. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: @stslavik Good point about rewarding answers.

Answer (score 0):

Prize ideas, hewing strictly to the theme of *taijiquan*:

- San Da / San Shou equipment: boxing gloves, hand wraps, headgear, or shin-guards.
- Books: I would assume that [Sun Lu Tang's Study of Taijiquan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556434626) is part of the canon. I liked Kennedy & Guo's [Historical Survey of M.A. Manuals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583941940) and [Jing Wu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583942424). Maybe something from Yang Jwing-Ming if you're into that.
- DVDs: maybe [Tim Cartmell's Sun style series](http://www.shenwu.com/sunStyleTaiji.html)? ([Also, less relevant](http://www.budovideos.com/shop/customer/search.php?substring=cartmell).)

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass some of these suggestions to CHAOS.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a lot of fun and might encourage the right kind of participation.

Could we organize something like this, say, every other month, or every quarter?

Comment: It definitely could. I've contacted Stack Exchange about this, and we're going ahead with the tai chi one first. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: Ooh, very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Something occurred to me.
Can we repeat the experiment with 'Karate' ? It is the same kind of umbrella term as 'Taichi'...

Comment: Not a bad idea. It's something to try in the future. We can see how this one goes first though.