# Tai Chi Week - A Martial Arts.SE Contest

Tags: discussion, status-completed, asking-questions, contests

The contest is now over. Thanks to everyone for participating in this. We'll be choosing the winner shortly and then letting Katey know about it soon. In the meantime, there is a new meta post regarding how the contest went, what was good, and what we can do to improve.

- [Reflections on the Tai Chi Topic Contest](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/reflections-on-the-tai-chi-topic-contest)

---

I've been in touch with Katey from the [CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) team about the [proposed tai chi contest](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/proposal-for-a-topic-of-the-week-contest-tai-chi), and we have the go-ahead to run this contest. Here is an outline of the rules and how the contest will be run. **Please feel free to share and promote this contest with others** and have them participate on the site.

## General Contest Rules

All users can ask and answer questions on the site and will be eligible for the contest. Most questions about the tai chi are welcome on the site. However, certain types of questions are not allowed. For more information, see the [faq](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq). Users who are suspended or require moderator intervention may be excluded from the contest depending on the severity any issues.

Answers must actually answer the question being asked. Replies which do not answer the question but add additional information should be reserved for comments.

This site is run by the community. Users with enough reputation can vote to close or delete questions and answers which they feel do not fit on the site. Moderators and Stack Exchange employees can close or delete questions at any time.

**You must be at least thirteen years old** to participate in the site, and agree to the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal). All content must adhere to the Stack Exchange Network [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

## Contest Dates and Format

The contest will last for **10 days**. The exact dates are:

- **Wednesday, May 16, 12:01 AM UTC - Saturday, May 26, 11:59 PM UTC**

No questions recorded outside of these periods will apply in the contest.

All questions must be related to tai chi and be tagged with [tai-chi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tai-chi) in order to be eligible for the contest during this time period.

Each eligible question is worth one entry for the asking user into the prize drawing. Questions must remain open, not be deleted, and have a net score of at least +3.

## Choosing the Winner

Winner will be chosen at random by the moderators from all eligible entries. The contest winner will receive a copy of [**A Study of Taijiquan**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556434626) by Sun Lutang.

If the winner lives outside of the USA, the user may be asked to purchase the item and submit the receipt to Stack Exchange for reimbursement in their native currency. **Stack Exchange reserves the right to substitute prizes for equally relevant and valuable replacements, due to lack of availability of the listed prizes at contest’s closing.**

## Contacting the Prize Winner

On or around May 26, the moderators will contact Stack Exchange to notify them of the winner who will then attempt to contact the winning user via the email addresses on their user account.

In the event that Stack Exchange is unable to contact a user, that user will have four weeks to contact Stack Exchange. If the user does not contact them within four weeks, a second drawing for the prize will be held as though that user were ineligible.

Employees and relatives of employees of Stack Exchange, Inc. and Fog Creek Software are not eligible to win any prizes. Moderators of the Martial Arts Stack Exchange have also elected to be ineligible for the contest.

Contest void where prohibited by law.

Comment: Nice work putting this together, Matt.